# Taking picture without displaying camera

Tags: android, image, camera

I want to take picture directly or with camera intent but when take picture button pressed in my application picture taken without showing camera application

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Camera API.

See the sample app at http://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/project.html